# Gradually migrate from Spring Boot MVC Monolith to JAVA Backend + React Frontend

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-mvc, react-redux

in my team we need and want to separate frontend from backend in order to improve user experience and separate development teams.

Right now we have a java spring boot MVC monolith rendering jsp templates to the broswer.
Frontend language choice is mandatory for us: React+Redux.

In this very moment we cannot fully develop the new frontend behind the scenes so we need to gradually integrate the "old" and "new" frontend.
We need separate codebases, on different remote repositories.

How can we handle this?

We explored some theoretical options, mainly:

1. have the static built files from React "inside" the war package **NOT DESIRED**
2. have the backend app picking up requests from the browser and rendering in some way the react app inside the selected JSPs
3. have the frontend app picking up requests from the browser, routing to the backend in case is an "old" part of the frontend

We are stuck at this point deciding how to proceed, can someone kindly help me out?

Sidenote: The web app is served via AWS cloud: we have a load balancer managing ubuntu instances with Tomcat + a provisioned MySQL Aurora DB. The main domain points at the load balancer

Answer (score 2):

React+Redux is a Single Page Application (SPA) that only servers static content. You can deploy it in an S3 bucket and serve it through Cloud Front.

In your Spring Boot code you should implement the REST API (or GraphQL) that will be consumed by the React App.

Therefore, you will have two code repositories, one for the React App and one for the Back End.

Some things to consider:

- Deployment: The react app and Spring Boot can be deployed separately. You should set up a CI/CD pipeline.
- CORS: The React App will be in a different domain than the back-end services. CORS should be properly configured in Spring Boot.
- Authentication: JWT authentication works well with this architecture.
- Back-end team and front-end team collaboration: GraphQL can solve some problems, but it may too much a change for your team. If you go with a REST API, you should document the API. Spring Boot can easily be integrated with Swagger.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. We are stuck figuring out the second point of your list. How can we render the ReactApp which resides on a different domain from within the main domain?

Comment: This is possible using CORS: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Hello, the team is almost done in configuring the new pieces of the puzzle. My problem is still without solution.
Everything in your reply is correct but it does not address my real problem, sure because I didn't explain my self in a good way.
We need to have a transition period during which a part of what the user sees is rendered by the new react app an the rest by the old MVC monolith thorugh JSPs.
What's the best approach to achieve that?

Comment: Do some research about A/B testing. Post a new questions with more details (deployment environment, constraints)