# Gradual integration of React frontend into Spring Boot MVC monolith

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-mvc, react-router

following up this question [Gradually migrate from Spring Boot MVC Monolith to JAVA Backend + React Frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69895624/gradually-migrate-from-spring-boot-mvc-monolith-to-java-backend-react-frontend/69896009?noredirect=1#comment124425919_69896009)

I need some extra help on a specific topic.

**AS-IS:** Spring Boot MVC monolith serving our app to customers. Controllers picking up requests and compiling JSPs templates. Authentication handled in house

**TO-BE:** Spring Boot REST API + REACT Frontend. Authentication handled by AWS Cognito.

We need to gradually migrate from AS-IS to TO-BE integrating step by step the new Frontend and REST API backend, taking away piece by piece from the "old" backend.

We have a working prototype of this temporary infrastructure, I tried to sketch it up on the following schema:

[image: Temporary infrastructure to gradually integrate new frontend and backend]

"old" MVC backend, "new" REST backend and frontend all have their separate code repository.

The "old" MVC backend is picking up requests from the browser.
We added a controller to serve the react frontend under the path *[www.main-domain.it/app](http://www.main-domain.it/app)*:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class TestReactController {

    @RequestMapping(value="**")
    public ModelAndView getReactPage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test_react");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

The JSP page holds a div id="root" to be targeted by React, and the scripts tag to include js e css chunks from the static s3 bucket holding the built frontend:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>React App</title>
    <link href="https://bucket-name.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/static/css/main.2ae47eeb.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script>!function(e){function r(r){for(var n,a,i=r[0],l=r[1],c=r[2],s=0,p=[];s<i.length;s++)a=i[s],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,a)&&o[a]&&p.push(o[a][0]),o[a]=0;for(n in l)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l,n)&&(e[n]=l[n]);for(f&&f(r);p.length;)p.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,c||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,i=1;i<t.length;i++){var l=t[i];0!==o[l]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=a(a.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function a(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,a),t.l=!0,t.exports}a.e=function(e){var r=[],t=o[e];if(0!==t)if(t)r.push(t[2]);else{var n=new Promise((function(r,n){t=o[e]=[r,n]}));r.push(t[2]=n);var u,i=document.createElement("script");i.charset="utf-8",i.timeout=120,a.nc&&i.setAttribute("nonce",a.nc),i.src=function(e){return a.p+"static/js/"+({}[e]||e)+"."+{3:"dafa9460"}[e]+".chunk.js"}(e);var l=new Error;u=function(r){i.onerror=i.onload=null,clearTimeout(c);var t=o[e];if(0!==t){if(t){var n=r&&("load"===r.type?"missing":r.type),u=r&&r.target&&r.target.src;l.message="Loading chunk "+e+" failed.\n("+n+": "+u+")",l.name="ChunkLoadError",l.type=n,l.request=u,t[1](l)}o[e]=void 0}};var c=setTimeout((function(){u({type:"timeout",target:i})}),12e4);i.onerror=i.onload=u,document.head.appendChild(i)}return Promise.all(r)},a.m=e,a.c=n,a.d=function(e,r,t){a.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},a.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},a.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=a(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(a.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)a.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},a.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return a.d(r,"a",r),r},a.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},a.p="./",a.oe=function(e){throw console.error(e),e};var i=this["webpackJsonpldl-frontend"]=this["webpackJsonpldl-frontend"]||[],l=i.push.bind(i);i.push=r,i=i.slice();for(var c=0;c<i.length;c++)r(i[c]);var f=l;t()}([])</script><!--     <script src="https://ldl-react-auth-test.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/static/js/2.28267f35.chunk.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://bucket-name.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/static/js/2.28267f35.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="https://bucket-name.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/static/js/main.e0713aa9.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

On the React side, we have the Router set up on basename="/app" in index.tsx:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/app">
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

And different routes in App.tsx:

```
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Prova />} />
   <Route path="login" element={<AuthPage />} />
   <Route path="prova2" element={<Prova2 />} />
</Routes>
```

With this setup, everything is working so far. Frontend build on S3 bucket and local Tomcat server spinning up the "old" backend.
When I get to main-domain.it/app the React frontend is correctly showing up and it works as expected.

**THE QUESTION:**
Now every time a new build of the frontend is created (manually) I need to manually change the scripts link, because names of the css and js chunks change everytime.

How can I automate the whole CD pipeline so that on every commit to a specific branch of the frontend rep, the new build gets online and the "old" backend can pick up the correct scripts link?

For other Frontend applications I personally use AWS Amplify service, is that a viable solution in this case? Can I use the only link I get from amplify to integrate the React frontend into the "old" backend?